# No data return for last night

Tags: onedrive

I use live sdk REST API to retrieve data from onedrive storage.

It contains no data in the response string event the status_code is 200.

I wonder if the apis.live.net/v5.0 is still alive from last night and where could I feedback this problem to?

thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be referred to Microsoft Support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For support, try going to http://onedrive.live.com and click the Settings wheel at the top righ corner. Select Feedback, and once you've inputted your issue, it will be routed to the right folks.